# Is it possible to implement user mode callouts in WFP (Windows Filtering Platform)?

Tags: c++, filter, wfp

Is it possible to implement user mode callouts in WFP (Windows Filtering Platform)? If so please share some related links or sample code.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible at this time. Although much of the Windows Filtering Platform (WFP) API is available in user mode you will trip over a version of this API call when you attempt to register a callout:

```
FwpsCalloutRegister3(
   _Inout_ void* deviceObject,
   _In_ const FWPS_CALLOUT3* callout,
   _Out_opt_ UINT32* calloutId
   );
```

It's the only way to register your classify/notify functions with WFP and if you're not a kernel device driver then you will not have a `deviceObject` to pass to this API call.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **User Mode vs. Kernel Mode**
>
> If the desired filtering can be done by using the standard filtering
>   functionality that is built in to the Windows Filtering Platform,
>   independent software vendors (ISVs) should write user-mode management
>   applications to configure the filter engine instead of writing
>   kernel-mode callout drivers. A kernel-mode callout driver should only
>   be written when you must process the network data in ways that cannot
>   be handled by the standard, built-in filtering functionality. For
>   information about how to write a user-mode Windows Filtering Platform
>   management application, see the Windows Filtering Platform
>   documentation in the Microsoft Windows SDK.